# Query Parameters in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular4-router

I want to create url in angular 4

For example:

http://localhost:4200/#/page/page2/6/abc/1234

but now i am using query params like this:

```
this.router.navigate(['page/page2/' + row.id],{ queryParams: {'name': row.name,'phnnumber': row.phnnumber}});
```

Comment: this.router.navigate(['page' , 'page2', row.id],{ queryParams: {'name': row.name,'phnnumber': row.phnnumber}});, add route component for this

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a route like this :

`{path : "page/page2/:rowId/:name/:phoneNumber" , component : "yourComponent" }` .

Later you can navigate to your route :

`this.router.navigate(['page/page2/' + row.id + "/" + row.name + "/" + row.phnnumber]);`